# Attention is all you need: During run/test time, when output is not available, how is the decoder used?

Tags: attention

In the famous paper "Attention is all you need" we see that in the Decoder we input the supposedly 'Output' sentence embeddings. During inference/test time, this output would not be available. E.g. in English to German training, Encoder will be input with English and Decoder will be input with German embeddings. However, we would not have the German translation during run/test time. Hence, how the decoder shall work since it requires the output (German) embeddings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoder generates the target sentence autoregresssively. At the very step, it has only one input, the special beginning of sentence token $\text{<s>}$. Using that, you compute the probability distribution of the first word $P(\bullet | \text{<s>})$. From that distribution, you take the most probable token (or several most probable ones in beam search) and you have the first token $w_1$. Therefore, in the next step, you have two embeddings, the self-attention will attend to you can compute distribution $P(\bullet | \text{<s>}, w_1)$ and so on until you generate the entire target sentence.